# How can I handle different (via frontend requested) tasks asynchronously, without interrupting a running process?

Tags: python, socket.io, python-asyncio, coroutine, fastapi

I would like to implement the following setup, probably using Python/FastAPI as backend & JavaScript as frontend. So far I have used fast-api/socketio for bidirectional communication (between frontend and backend) and asyncio for asynchronous handling of coroutines, but so far I could not find a satisfactory solution.

Does anyone have an idea for the following problem?
Using the frontend, the user should be able to send a request to retrain a machine learning model. While the retraining is taking place, the user should still be able to e.g. get predictions from the "old" model or visualize the data by requesting it via the frontend. The retraining process should not be interrupted (for too long) and after completion the user should be informed that the "new" model is ready.

Please find my approach so far for two tasks running asynchronously without using await asyncio.sleep() below. 
 Question: (how) will this approach with asyncio.gather work for the task of 'continuously checking for prediction_requests", and further giving back the prediction result?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from fastapi_socketio import SocketManager, socket_manager
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import asyncio
from datetime import date

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def main():
        
        await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.to_thread(trainModel),
        printNumber()
        )
    

def trainModel():
    print('train model startet')
    data = pd.read_csv('spam_data.csv')

    # Text Preprocessing
    import re # regex library
    print('before preprocessor')
    def preprocessor(text):
        text = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', text) # Effectively removes HTML markup tags
        emoticons = re.findall('(?::|;|=)(?:-)?(?:\)|\(|D|P)', text)
        text = re.sub('[\W]+', ' ', text.lower()) + ' '.join(emoticons).replace('-', '')
        return text
    print('after preprocessor')

    # Train, Test Split
    print('start train, test split')
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X = data['Message'].apply(preprocessor)
    y = data['Category']

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

    
    # Training a Neural Network Pipeline
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report
    from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    print('start training a NN Pipeline')
    
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents=None, lowercase=False, 
                            max_features=700, 
                            ngram_range=(1,1))
    neural_net_pipeline = Pipeline([('vectorizer', tfidf), 
                                    ('nn', MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(700, 700)))])

    neural_net_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print ('after fit')
    model = neural_net_pipeline
    print('model is trained')
    return model 


async def printNumber():
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)
```

Other approaches relied on using asyncio.sleep(), but I do not want to interrupt the trainModel() process and without .sleep and .gather both methods run one after another.

```
@app.get("/")
async def main():
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(trainModel())
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(printNumber())
    model = await task2
    await task1
```

Comment: This question is a little bit broad right now. You mentioned you have tried implementing this already, but the results were unsatisfactory. What, specifically, was the problem with what you came up with? You're more likely to get an answer if you have a more targeted problem that needs solving.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your comment!  I wanted to keep it quite general in case someone has already made something similar and would suggest something complete different, but i updated it now with my last approach & thoughts. :)